# Who is the unnamed astronaut in this uncredited photo used in commercial promotional material?

Tags: astronauts, identify-this-object

When I linked back to [Do ISS astronauts notice, or experience symptoms of elevated CO2 levels? Do they wear monitors regularly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24600/12102) in this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26205/12102), I was surprised to find that I hadn't named the astronaut shown in the image. Clicking through to other links, I found that her image is unreferenced and uncredited in several places!!

- Gas Sensing Solutions' promotional material [Innovative sensor technology assists NASA with vital wearable CO2 monitoring equipment](https://www.gassensing.co.uk/news/innovative-sensor-technology-assists-nasa-with-vital-wearable-co2-monitoring-equipment/)
- SST Sensing's promotional material [Innovative Sensor Technology Assists NASA with Vital Wearable CO2 Monitoring Equipment](http://www.sstsensing.com/innovative-sensor-technology-assists-nasa-with-vital-wearable-co2-monitoring-equipment/)
- CO2meter.com's blog [NASA Wearable CO2 Monitor uses CozIR Sensor](https://www.co2meter.com/blogs/news/co2-sensor-nasa-wearable-co2-monitor) simply thanks Gas Sensing Solutions for use of the image.

If it had been Tim Peake, these UK companies might have been more mindful perhaps?

**Question:** Who is the unnamed astronaut in this uncredited photo used in commercial promotional material?

Comment: There is a clue however. In the URL of the image used in the Gas Sensing Solutions page linked above, the file name is `katenasa.jpg`. We don't have a separate `identify-this-astronaut` tag, so I've used `identify-this-object`. No "objectification of astronauts" intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be Dr. Kathleen "Kate" [Rubins](https://www.nasa.gov/astronauts/biographies/kathleen-rubins/biography/).

[image]

Comment: So it's Dr. Kathleen "Kate" Rubins Ph.D., the first person to sequence DNA in space, rather than "[Kate Nasa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26206/who-is-the-unnamed-astronaut-in-this-uncredited-photo-used-in-commercial-promoti/26209#comment77345_26206)". Thanks! I've edited both linked items to reflect the new information.